# Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:59074: address already in use

Tags: windows, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel

I am trying to figure out how profiles work and I'm looking at when each profile is executed.

When I run my sample application on IIS, there is not problem. But when I run by clicking "WebApplication1" and it tries to use Kestrel, I get the following error in the console:

Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:59074: address already in use.

I tried using netstat, netstat -a, and netstat -q.

There is nothing showing up with that address. This is on a local development machine. How do I find out how to fix the binding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running two dotnet core application  read from config port number and iOS port should be different    with clicking webapplication

Comment: So, I need to change the applicationUrl in launchsettings.json to be different for each? Does it consider it to be blocked by IIS when running Kestrel?

Comment: Yes make 2 copies one for iis deploy other for command line run